# Changing MDI background affects child form background

Tags: vb.net

Hie 
      I have changed background of MDI form using for each loop of controls which works perfect,but when I make a form MDI container true the form background resets to MDI default color(gray), is there a  way to avoid it?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?496227-Changing-the-Background-of-an-MDI-Parent-Form&highlight=).